# .Net application instance terminates after 13 min, 20 sec whether user is idle or not

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, iis, internet-explorer-9

Here's some bullet points:

- Enterprise .NET and Silverlight app running on a client's Win2k8R2 server
- Runs in IE9
- 13 minutes, 20 seconds (800,000 ms) after a user logs into the app, the browser window it's running in closes (any other open browser windows are not affected).
- Termination doesn't affect concurrent users, if user1 logs in at 0 minutes and user2 logs in at 5 minutes, user1's application window will close at 13:20 and user2's will at 18:20.
- It doesn't matter if the user is idle or actively using the application, the window still closes at the same time
- The timeout length set in the Web.config is 30 minutes, IIS app pool has idle time-out set to 20 minutes, IIS recycle set to every 29 hours.
- There shouldn't be a setting in the app code that would cause this to happen: we distribute the same exact application to numerous clients and have never had this issue before.

I've looked at the IIS-Configuration Administrative/Operational logs and application logs and there aren't any significant messages in any of them when the browser terminates.

This is a pretty broad problem description, just testing the waters to see if anyone has seen anything like this issue before and if people have any ideas of where to keep looking.

Comment: the browser window closing sounds like a client-side thing (SL, most likely) - frankly, I'm not sure that looking at web.config and IIS config/logs is related. But I do appreciate the extra context, because obviously when the origin of the problem is unknown: the origin of the problem is unknown.

Comment: Is the SL app in constant communication with the server?

Comment: Thanks for the response, Marc! Yes, it's in constant communication.

Comment: does this happen on that particular client? or in all clients? if in particular then you might wanna check client browser settings.

Comment: Just for this particular client, I'll check that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by McAfee antivirus running on the client's machine. After disabling it, no problems.